# Base and Independence proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Adapted from Axler,

> [image]

Could someone explain the last part for me? How does the unique representation imply all the constants are suddenly $0$? We are trying to show it is linearly independent, he doesn't know this yet, so why is he doing that?

Please excuse the length of this question.

Comment: We know automatically that $0$ has only one representation as a linear combination of the $v_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a base $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$, the zero vector can be clearly written as $$0=\sum_{i=1}^n 0\cdot v_i$$

Since we're assuming the representation is **unique**, that is $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i=\sum_{i=1}^n b_iv_i\implies a_i=b_i$$ the fact that $$0=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_i$$ gives that $\lambda_i=0$, so the $v_i$ are linearly independent.

Note that linear independence is a rewording of *the zero vector is uniquely represented by the span*, since linearity gives $$(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\iff(a_1-b_1,\ldots,a_n-b_n)=(0,\ldots,0)$$ which is precisely what we're saying above.

Comment: Why can't there be some constants that gives $0 = c_1v_1 - c_1v_2 + \dots 0v_n$?

Comment: @sidht Come again?

Comment: I am just saying $0$ can also be written like $$0 = c_1v_1 - c_2v_2 + 0v_3 + \dots + 0v_n$$. Since the representation is unique, say I have another combination $b_1v_1 + b_2v_2 + \dots + b_nv_n = 0$. Setting them equal imples $b_1 = c_1$ and $b_2 = -c_1$, so $b_1 = -b_2$ and the other constants are $0$

Comment: @sidht Sure, but since the representation is unique, we must have that each of the coefficients is $0$.

Comment: Why? I am having seriously problems understanding that part. We want to show the set is linearly independent, by assuming the only way is that the constants are all $o$ isn't that circular logic or some sort?

Comment: @sidht: If the coefficients are not all zero then $$0=0v_1+\cdots+0v_n$$ and $$0=c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n$$ are two different representations of the vector $0$ as linear combinations of the $v_i$, contrary to the assumption that every vector can be written in one and only one way as a linear combination of the $v_i$, a contradiction.

Comment: I know this is going to be a very stupid question. Suppose say $$0 = 5v_1 - 5v_1 + 0v_3 + \dots + 0v_n$$ where $v_1 = v_2$ (so assume our set of vectors actually is linearly dependent). Then what? Why are we favoring the $0$ constants representation?

Comment: @sidht You're forgetting what you're trying to prove. We need to show that unique representation implies linearly independent. The case where $v_1=v_2$ is utterly irrelevant because that isn't consistent with unique representation. If I wanted to show that $n<0$ implies $n<1$, I can't say "well what happens if $n=2$? Why are we favoring negative numbers?" because that has nothing to do with the hypothesis ($n<0$) we're trying to get results ($n<1$) out of. Beware mathematical amnesia.

Comment: Rather than inconsistent with unique representation, is it wrong? I feel like *I* am the one who is delving into circular logic here now.

Comment: @sidht Do you remember what you're trying to prove? To prove $A\implies B$, you assume $A$ and show that $B$ must follow from this assumption. Here we're showing that unique representation implies linearly independent. So we assume every vector can be uniquely represented as a linear combination of the $v_i$. It must follow then that the $v_i$ are linearly independent, for otherwise $0$ would have two different representations as a linear combination of the $v_i$ contrary to our assumptions. Talking about situations where unique representation fails is irrelevant to what's going on here.

Comment: @anon, *It must follow then that the vi are linearly independent*, right but you only know that after you deduce the constants are all $0$. I am just saying if it happens $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ can only yield $0$ with say $0 = v_1 + 2v_2 + 0v_3 + \dots + 0v_n$, then this set may not be linearly independent

Comment: Oh wait, I see the problem with my example. How about this anon, since we know that $0$ can always be written as $0 = 0v_1 + 0v_2 + \dots + 0v_n$ and since the representation $0 = a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n$ is unique, it really is true that all constants are $0$, thus linear independence follows

Comment: @sidht Yes, that's what I've said a few times over now. You cannot say that $0$ has a nontrivial representation in terms of the $v_i$ (as you've asked about a number of times) because that would contradict the assumption of uniqueness we've made.

Comment: @anon, thanks. If you had seen my other questions, you would probably guess I have a reading disability.